# Loopback - Custom route under RestAPI route

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to add a custom express route under my restAPI root, but when trying to reach this address it not found.

For instance, if the restAPI root is `/api`, so the following custom route is unreachable (I want the method sayHello to be called with `/api/sayHello`):

```
app.get('/api/sayHello', 
  function (req, res, next) {
    res.send('hello!');
  }
);
```

The error I'm getting is :

> "error":
>
> {"name":"Error","status":404,"message":"There is no method to
>   handle GET /sayHello","statusCode":404,"stack":"Error: There is no
>   method to handle GET /sayHello\n at restUrlNotFound
>   (/workspace/sandboxlauncher/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/rest-adapter.js:337:17)\n
>   at Layer.handle as handle_request\n at trim_prefix
>   (/workspace/project_folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)\n
>   at
>   /workspace/project_folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7\n
>   at Function.process_params
>   (/workspace/project_folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)\n
>   at next
>   (/workspace/project_folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)\n
>   at jsonParser
>   (/workspace/project_folder/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:100
>   :40)\n at Layer.handle as handle_request\n at trim_prefix
>   (/workspace/project_folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)\n
>   at
>   /workspace/project_folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7"}}

Am I doing something wrong?
Is there any other approach to add such custom route?
Tried to find an answer to the question in [loopback's doc regarding to express routes](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Add+a+custom+Express+route), but found nothing.

My rest-api.js file :

```
module.exports = function mountRestApi( server ) {
  var restApiRoot = server.get( 'restApiRoot' );
  server.use( restApiRoot, server.loopback.rest() );
};
```

My config.json file contains the definition of restApiRoot as follows:

```
  "restApiRoot": "/api"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's in your datasources.json and rest-api.js?

Comment: Only the default db (which comes with memory connector)

Comment: And your config.json...the api root should be set here

Comment: If your api root is `/api` you don't need to include that in the route handler. Your route handler can just be `app.get('/sayHello'`

Comment: Good question, I wish it had a good answer.